# JQuery Linked checkbox and use of function "each()

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I'm posting here because i cant find any solution.
I'm not a native speaker so i'll do my best to explain my problem.

There is what i call "checkboxs mother". If they are checked, their sons are disabled. I want to do a "clean" code, that's why i tried to user .each() but it didnt work as i wanted.
Here my javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {

        $("#check_prev").each(function() {
            this.click(enable_cb(i));
            i++;
        });


    });

    function enable_cb(id) {
        if (this.checked) {

            $("input.input_panne" + id).attr("disabled", true);
            $("input.input_panne" + id).attr("checked", false);
            $("span.check_panne" + id).css("color", "#D8D8D8");

        } else {
            $("input.input_name" + id).removeAttr("disabled");
            $("span.check_agent" + id).css("color", "black");

            $("input.input_panne" + id).removeAttr("disabled");
            $("span.check_panne" + id).css("color", "black");

        }
    }
</script>
```

I already tried ".concat()" but it's not working. Also the "checkbox mother" are named like this : check_prev1, check_prev2 etc. Sons, like this : input_panne1, input_panne2.

Thanks for your help... working on it for almost 2 days and no solution in sight ... gonna kill my self

EDIT: Here's the HTML CODE

```
<body>
    <input type="checkbox" class="mere" data-mere="1">
    <input type="checkbox" class="son son1">
    <input type="checkbox" class="son son1">
    <input type="checkbox" class="mere" data-mere="2">
    <input type="checkbox" class="son son2">
    <input type="checkbox" class="son son2">
    <input type="checkbox" class="mere" data-mere="3">
    <input type="checkbox" class="son son3">
    <input type="checkbox" class="son son3">
</body>
```

Comment: can you share the html sample for checkbox and the son elements

Comment: The cause is expecting `i` to retain its value much later when the event occurs. `Arun P Johny`'s answer below avoids that problem, but a simpler answer is possible. Can you provide a sample of your HTML (output from browser and not source) too to mock it up?

Comment: Please share your HTML code (o/p on browser) so that we an help

Answer (score 0):

Since id of an element must be unique, assign a class like `check_prev` to all mother checkboxes then

```
$(function () {
    $(".check_prev").click(enable_cb);
});

function enable_cb() {
    var id = this.id.replace('check_prev', '')
    if (this.checked) {
        $("input.input_panne" + id).prop("disabled", true);
        $("input.input_panne" + id).prop("checked", false);
        $("span.check_panne" + id).css("color", "#D8D8D8");

    } else {
        $("input.input_name" + id).prop("disabled", false);
        $("span.check_agent" + id).css("color", "black");

        $("input.input_panne" + id).prop("disabled", false);
        $("span.check_panne" + id).css("color", "black");

    }
}
```

Comment: mmmmh it's not working. Why does this line do  var id = this.id.replace('check_prev', '') ?

Comment: can you share the html sample

Comment: @SeNi instead of the PHP code... can you go to view source in browser and share the generated html

Comment: <body>
    <input type="checkbox" class="mere" data-mere="1">
    <input type="checkbox" class="son son1">
    <input type="checkbox" class="son son1">
    <input type="checkbox" class="mere" data-mere="2">
    <input type="checkbox" class="son son2">
    <input type="checkbox" class="son son2">
    <input type="checkbox" class="mere" data-mere="3">
    <input type="checkbox" class="son son3">
    <input type="checkbox" class="son son3">
</body>

Comment: I can show the exact same code, but this is like this one